# The value for the useBean class attribute com.realtor.website.WebdbBean is invalid

Tags: java, apache, jsp, javabeans, tomcat5.5

I am facing an error after moved my site from one server to other.

My problem is java bean is working fine if page is at root folder. for example "mydomain.com/page1.jsp" is working fine BUT if I put the page in folder then it's give me below  error. for example "mydomain.com/test/page1.jsp" is give me error.

Error is :

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /office_listing.jsp(29,0) The value for the useBean class attribute com.realtor.website.WebdbBean is invalid.
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:148)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1204)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$UseBean.accept(Node.java:1117)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2216)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2222)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:457)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2166)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3384)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:207)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:326)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:307)
>       org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
>       org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:565)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:309)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
>       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

---

JSP  code is :

```
    <%@page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java"     import="java.sql.*,java.lang.*" import="java.text.*" import="java.util.*" errorPage="" %>

    <jsp:useBean class="com.realtor.website.WebdbBean" id="webdb" scope="session"/>
```

Can anyone guide me what can be the problem. OR do I need to take care anything specially when I change my server? Earlier and now, both time there is linux server Apache tomcat 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `WebdbBean` class? The `WebdbBean.class` must be at `WEB-INF/classes/com/realtor/website`

Comment: Yes, exactly the bean is at WEB-INF/classes/com/realtor/website location.

Answer (score 0):

This error basically means that the following

```
WebdbBean webdb = new WebdbBean();
```

has failed. Given the fact that it works fine in another page (and that you didn't typo'ed the `class` attribute), it's definitely in the classpath, so a possible cause of `ClassNotFoundException` can be scratched. Left behind that the bean's construction has plain failed. Apparently you're doing something in the default constructor which can possibly throw an unhandled exception. Its stacktrace should then be visible in the server logs. Read it and fix the root cause accordingly.

Comment: To make sure this problem, I have created one JSP page called "testPage.jsp" and put it on two different location of the server. One at the root folder and other at the newly created folder "TestFolder". So in that case I have two url to test.
1) mydomain.com/testPage.jsp 
2) mydomain.com/TestFolder/testPage.jsp 

first one is working fine and giving me result on page. BUT second one is giving error "The value for the useBean class attribute com.realtor.website.WebdbBean is invalid".

Comment: So if there is problem in constructor then first one should also give error (If I am not wrong) But it is working good.

SO I think bean has perfect constructor. 

Now in this case what can be other problem??